# fetching id_customer which are not exiting in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have any array of id_customer or ask list of id_customers like `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`.

I am trying to write an mysql query to get the list of the `id_customer` that are not exiting in the table from the above give list of or array of `id_customer`

> **Example** : If in the table I have id_customer (4,8,1)
>
> **Result** : I want to get is (2,3,5,6,7,9)

**Condition :** Using single mysql query subquery are allowed. and by pass the list of the or array of id_customer as above I have mentioned . I have considered it as `$customer_list_id` and I am passing this php variablein the query

```
SELECT id_customer FROM customer WHERE id_customer NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) GROUP BY id_customer
```

When I am use this query i am getting empty array. But the result I require is (2,3,5,6,7,9)

Comment: let us know the mysql query you are executing.

Comment: Maybe `where not in (ids)`?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu you check the question .

Comment: It is not possible to get not existing data if id_customer is your primary key.You need to check it from php

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu No, its not a primary key

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
where <> in (ids)
```